# Solving the Recurrence

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I am given `F(0)=X` and `F(i)=(A⋅F(i−1)^2 + B⋅F(i−1) + C)%1000000` for `1≤i≤N`.

Now given `N`,`A`,`B`,`C` and `X`, how to find all `N` elements effectively?

I need to divide these N elements in 2 sets where largest element goes in 1st set ,2nd largest in 2nd set , 3rd largest in 1st set and so on...and at the end need to find absolute differnece of the sum of elements of both the sets.

Can i find this difference without computing all elements as N can be as large as `10^7` and `A`,`B`,`C`,`X` are upto at max 100.

Comment: What is the use-case for that? (original problem may be)

Comment: @AlmaDo I need to calculate absolute differnece of the sum of elements of both the sets.

Comment: @AlmaDo u can say it a tricky task ..:p

Comment: @user132263 this looks like an increasing function. like its min at i=0 & it peeks at i=N. Can you confirm?

Comment: @hemanth i doubt about that.How can u say that will it not depend on values of A,B,C, or X

Comment: @user132263 What are the min values that A, B , C , X can take?

Comment: @hemanth They at minimum can be 0

Answer (score 3):

Note that the next element of the sequence depends only on the previous one, and there are no more than M=1000000 different elements since each result is an integer taken modulo 1000000. Thus the sequence is periodic from some point. You can generate the first few elements (no more than M) until you find the period, and then immediately know how many of each element there are if the total number of elements is N.

Now, 10^6 is at least some improvement when compared to 10^7. And once you know for each number from 0 to 999999 how many times it occurs in the sequence, you can find the required difference in O(M) operations, too.

Comment: Hey could u please explain somewhat more by some pseudocode or so..am not getting u

Comment: What exactly is not clear? The main point is, if F(x) = F(y) then F(x+1) = F(y+1), F(x+2) = F(y+2) and so on. Furthermore, each F(x) is an integer between 0 and 999999, so no later than after 1000000 steps, we will find some F(i) = F(j).

Comment: How to find required difference in O(M) operations ?

Comment: Suppose there are 15 numbers 999999, no 999998's, 14 numbers 999997, 15 numbers 999996, 14 numbers 999995 and so on. Of them, 14 999999's form seven pairs with zero difference. The first non-zero difference pair is 999999-999997=2. Next go 12 999997's in six zero pairs, and the next non-zero pair is 999997-999996. Next go 14 999996's in seven zero pairs, after that 14 99995's in seven zero pairs, and so on.

Comment: You will need O(M) memory to store the number of occurrences of 0, 1, ..., M-1. We can also store for each such number K the first x such that F(x)=K. After that, when some integer B occurs for the second time (its number of occurrences becomes 2), we already know which integer it is (B), and when it first occurred (say, at time y: F(y)=B). Thus we can calculate the length of the period. We already know the elements of the period, too: they are the integers with the first time of occurrence >=y.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I wouldn't fear to compute those `10^7` elements. As they range in `[0 1000000[`, it is acceptable to compute the histogram of the values (1000000 counters), that you will post-process to get the desired information (and follow @Gassa).

Take care of overflow when iterating the formula, as `F^2` won't fit in 32 bits.