# what is an efficient algorithm for solving recurrence relation for 2nd order problems?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, recurrence

I want to solve a recurrence relation with quadratic term in it.

For example..    `T(n)= T(n-1)^2 + T(n-1) + 2` is a recurrence relation and I have to print its sum mod 100000.

How can I do it if without using a simple brute-force method?

Comment: 1) what do you mean by "print its *sum*"? do you want to calculate T(n)? 2) what's the base case?

Comment: no by sum I mean (T(1)+T(2)+...+T(N)) MOD 100000.

Comment: i didnt get ur second question? are you asking me the best case solution or what!?

Comment: for every recursion, there's a base case, to *terminate* the recursion. eg: what's T(1)?

Comment: T(1)=123 is the base case. Gotta start somewhere.

Comment: How is this question on topic? This should be on the math site.

Comment: ok...you can assume T(1) = 3

Comment: I am not asking how to solve the recursion...i just want to know the algorithm for using it...so I guess my topic is good enough.

Comment: @EricLippert it seems to be on-topic here because it's about a computer algorithm

Comment: If n is much larger then modulo (100000), than ideas from this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22254011/solving-the-recurrence/22257509#22257509) can help.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how big `n` can be (say, around 10,000,000), you may get away with a simple `for` loop that would run in a small time (e.g. around a second).

I can't tell if you could find a mathematical formula for a generic `T(1)` and/or generic recursion, but my guess is that you can't. Nevertheless, I could tell you of a mathematical property that would help you solve your problem. It is called [congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). In short, this is the syntax:

```
a =(15)= b
```

means 15 divides `b - a`. The actual mathematical symbol is a `=` with three lines and the number is written above it, but I can't really type it!

Now here are a couple of theorems useful for you:

1.

```
a =(n)= b  \
            > => a =(n)= c
b =(n)= c  /
```

2.

```
a =(n)= b  =>  a+c =(n)= b+c
```

3.

```
a =(n)= b  =>  a*c =(n)= b*c
```

4.

```
a =(n)= b  =>  a^2 =(n)= b^2
```

They can be easily proved by writing `a` and `b` as:

```
a = k1*n+r
b = k2*n+r
```

and apply the transformations and make sure that in the end, `b - a` is still divisible by `n`.

---

That said, your algorithm becomes as follows (assuming you want the sum of T1 to TN mod M):

```
T = 3        /* initial T1 */
TSum = T     /* initial sum */

for i=1 to N
    T = (T^2 % M + T + 2) % M
    TSum = (TSum + T) % M
```

The important thing to notice here is that `T` and `TSum` are always bounded by `M` and the maximum intermediate result is from the expression `T^2` (for non-trivial `M`s) which can take a maximum of `(M-1)^2`.

Therefore, in your implementation, you don't actually need to deal with very large numbers, but merely with a datatype large enough to hold with `(M-1)^2`.  In C, a `uint64_t` would do. Note that with `M=100000`, `(M-1)^2` doesn't fit in a 32-bit integer.

This algorithm is `O(N)` by the way, so unless `N` is really large or unless it's in a very frequent loop, it should be fast enough for your daily needs!

---

**Edit**

The problem can actually be solved in `O(M)` rather than `O(N)`. This is due to the fact that all `T(i)` are in the range of `[0, M-1)` and therefore computing upto `T(M+1)`, you would certainly cycle back. Since `T(n)` depends solely on `T(n-1)`, then getting a repeated value for `T(n-1)` would result in the same chain of values as the first time.

So, let's unroll `T` and `TSum` to better observe how this can exploited. Assume `T` generates values `A`, `B`, ..., `Z` and after `Z`, it cycles back to `K` and after a couple of cycles it finishes on `P` (because we reached `N`):

```
T    A   B   C   D   E   ... K   ...  Z   K   ... Z   K   ... Z   ... K   ... P
TSum AS  BS  CS  DS  ES  ... KS  ...  ZS  KS2 ... ZS2 KS3 ... ZS3 ... KSt ... PSt
```

So your goal is to calculate `PSt`. The idea is to calculate up to `KS2`, take its difference from `KS`, multiply it by `t` and add it to `KS` to get `KSt`. Then add the remaining to get `PSt`.

The algorithm is as follows:

```
Sums=[M times 0]    /* initially, no sum is calculated */
Indices=[M times 0] /* Indices[i] = I means Sums[i] corresponds to T(1)+...+T(I) */
T = 3           /* initial T1 */
TSum = T        /* initial sum */
Sums[T] = TSum
Indices[T] = 1

for i=2 to N
    T = (T^2 % M + T + 2) % M
    if Sums[T] != 0         /* a loop is detected */
        break

    TSum = (TSum + T) % M
    Sums[T] = TSum
    Indices[T] = i

if i == N
    return TSum

/* compute how many cycles */
cycle_length = i - Indices[T]
t = (N - Indices[T]) / cycle_length

/* add sum of the cycles immediately */
TSum = (Sums[T] + t * (TSum - Sums[T])) % M

/* add what is left */
for i=Indices[T] + t * cycle_length+1 to N
    T = (T^2 % M + T + 2) % M
    TSum = (TSum + T) % M
```

Note: There may be off-by-one errors in index calculations. If you plan on using this algorithm, double check to make sure it doesn't miss any `T(i)` or sum it twice.

Comment: and what if n is larger than 10,00,00,000.

Comment: I think O(log n) is what OP is looking for... I would describe your approach as "simple brute force"

Comment: @NiklasB., that's right. This is a simple brute force. However, an even simpler and slower brute force (although more difficult to implement actually!) would simply calculate T and TSum no matter how large they get. I wrote this answer because I thought the OP may not have considered this optimization and this optimization could have made a simple brute force all right.

Comment: Good observation with the cycle length :) The same principle applies when your recurrence depends on `k` earlier terms, in which case your cycle length is smaller than `M^k`

Comment: I added an update to limit the execution rate. @tacet, now try to put `n` on top of it! ;)

Comment: @Shahbaz och, [here_you are!](http://mathurl.com/k9hm23j.png) ;P mathurl.com is nice site. Btw. Why not a ≡ b (mod n)? Simple, correct notation.

Comment: @tacet, if SO supported TeX math, it would have been easy. I prefer `a =n= b` though, it's easier to write, and closer to the notation than `a ≡ b (mod n)`.

Comment: I would say `a ≡ b (mod n)` is pretty standard notation and much more common than placing the modulus on top of the congruence sign

Answer (score 2):

The is a more mathematical way to solve recurrence equations for example using z-transforms or generating functions. Take the z-transform of the equation in question and then find f(z) the generating polynomial for your recurrence and take inverse z-transform to get the discrete space function in closed form.

**Steps:**

1. Take *z*-transform of *T(n)*
2. Find *F(z)* in terms of *z* which is the generating polynomial for your recurrence.
3. Take *Inverse(F(z))* to get the closed form equation for the recurrence.
4. After getting the closed form you can directly find *T(n)* from *n*
5. You can further find closed form for the summation.

Comment: Can you give an example of how this is done for this particular recurrence?  It might be very interesting :)

Comment: @NiklasB. The best example of using z-transform for solving recurrences is solution of fibonacci sequence closed form.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279868/causal-inverse-z-transform-of-fibonacci

Comment: and even better examples in this free book: http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html ;-)

Comment: @fex: Thanks, I think I came across that some time, but didn't remember it mention anything about "z-transform".

Comment: The Z-transform only applies to linear recurrences, and even then not all types of coefficients. The other name is generating function. But the square of T in the recurrence in the question prohibits the use of recurrences. The best one can do here is to observe that (T[n]+0.5)=(T[n-1]+0.5)^2+2.25, which is not really helpful to find a closed form solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually more of a math question, but anyway, here’s a few things you should consider:

1. If you’re only interested in the sum mod 100,000, you can perform all calculations mod 100,000. (Don’t try and use that in a homework answer if you have no idea why it’s true. But that is really a math question then.)
2. You have a first-order recurrence equation (your title is wrong, by the way), and really should implement it not by recursion, but iteratively.

Rough pseudo-code (hoping against hope you’ll learn from it, not just take it for homework, but then again, the only one you’d hurt would be yourself):

```
value = 3 // T(1)
sum = value
N.times do
  value = (value^2 + value + 2) % 100000
  sum = (sum + value) % 100000
end
```

For a more math-oriented answer, you could also consider how to get a recursion formula for the sum S(n) and then compute a closed-form solution for that.

Comment: The whole point is what you can do for large n when the iterative approach is too slow but you can't solve the recurrence

Comment: In general, nothing. There are recurrences which you can partly solve, e.g., for 2^n, and that would give you an O(log(n)) algorithm (see Knuth’s treatise on the Josephus problem for an example), but getting faster than O(n) will take some partial solving of the recurrence equation.

Comment: For linear recurrences like Fibonacci, 3-Fibonacci etc, where F(n) is a linear combination of `F(n-k), ..., F(n-1)` there is a general solution approach involving matrix multiplication that runs in `O(k^3 * log n)`.  I think OP is wondering whether something similar exists if you have quadratic terms

Comment: @NiklasB. But that algorithm translates into an explicit solution (which may or may not involve constants describing the roots of polynomials that cannot be expressed in radicals, but can be approximated to arbitrary precision), since you can give an explicit formula for A^n.